# For double integrals, when do you decide to use a function as the limit?

Tags: calculus, integration

I read that double integrals' limit can be decided based on the 'boundaries' of the shape on the x and y axis.

[image]

For example in the image above, we can see that the region R in question is between -1 and 0 for both the x and y axis. So how do we decide when to use either the absolute or the function limit for the integration?

Answer (score 0):

The integration area $B$ is bounded by two interesting curves. The value of the integral depends in a crucial way on the exact shape of these curves. If one of these curves is replaced by, say, $x+y^4=0$ you get another result.

Now, if you enter just $-1$ and $0$ into your computation this means that you don't care about the exact shape of $B$ at all, and just take the integral over the full square $[-1,0]^2$.

Therefore the correct setting is
$$\int_Bf(x,y)\>dA=\int_{-1}^0\int_{-\sqrt{-x}}^{-x^2} f(x,y)\>dy\>dx\ .$$

Comment: If I may rephrase this answer in a layman (and probably conceptually wrong) way, we determine the limits for the two integral as such:

left (first) integral: the absolute limits with respect to x
right (second integral): the limits with respect to y. Since we have function for y, we substitute those functions in.

Is this alright?